# Passwords are stolen, how to fix?

Tags: security

I have a couple sets of passwords. They are used in different websites.

I received a notice from Hulu which said that someone logged in my account in Europe (I live in USA). I used PW1 for hulu.

A few minutes from that notice, I received an email from google which said that someone tried to log in my gmail. I used PW2 for gmail.

Now, my question is why two sets of password are stolen at the same time? Or people is not stolen my pw but something that can bypass the pw (maybe cookies from my PC)

The other question is how to fix?

Comment: Did someone *try* to log into your gmail account, or did they *succeed* in logging in? If they tried but failed, it’s likely they just tried the same one they’d gotten to work with Hulu... and they probably tried it a bunch of other places, so I’d assume they got into everything you used PW1 for.

Answer (score 3):

Passwords can be broken by brute force or by dictionary attack or by
being on the list of popular passwords.

The only thing you can do is change all your passwords. Ensure that they are long enough
and contain characters of many types (upper & lower case, numbers, special characters).

Scan also your computer using several well-known antivirus products, just in case
you are infected with a keylogger. Never use any password when connected to a
public network, and preferably use a VPN when on such a network.

For more information see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Preferably make sure your machine is clean first and change your mail account password first. Consider using a password manager.

Comment: Agreed. I propose [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/) that can also generate uncrackable passwords and remember them. Never reuse a password.

Comment: It could be that the OP's computer is infected by malware or keyloggers stealing saved or entered passwords.

Comment: I miss one very important detail in this answer which makes me not voting this up. Using the same password everywhere is very bad. A website can get hacked, they get the password, then they get access everywhere. I would definitely recommend a password mananger and then replace all passwords everywhere to random passwords stored in the password manager. There are good password managers out there.

Comment: I would also suggest using 2 / multi factor authentication where possible, Gmail support this however Hulu unfortunately doesn't.